# How can I transform an object schema's property schemas to derive a new object schema?

Tags: joi

Is there a way to introspect and then transform a Joi schema?

I see there is [`any.describe()`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#anydescribe) which "returns an object that represents the internal configuration of the schema" but then I have to map that internal configuration back to schema builder calls and re-create the schema myself.

e.g. given

```js
const PersonSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.string().required(),
  lastName: Joi.string().required(),
  age: Joi.number().required(),
});
```

I want to define a generic function to take any object schema and make its properties support arrays of the original type equivalent to the following:

```js
const PersonFilterSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  firstName: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()).optional(),
  lastName: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().required()).optional(),
  age: Joi.array().items(Joi.number().required()).optional(),
});
```

i.e. I want to be able to write something like this:

```js
function createFilterSchema(schema) {
  return Joi.object().keys(
    Object.fromEntries(
      schema
        .getEntries()
        .map(([key, value]) => [key, Joi.array().items(value).optional()])
    )
  );
}
```

and then elsewhere use it with whatever raw schemas I have:

```js
const PersonFilterSchema = createFilterSchema(PersonSchema);
```